# SyncToy Failed in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, synchronization

I am trying to use the Microsoft SyncToy to sync files between two web servers.
I can run the sync job in both GUI and the command line mode.
Command:
"C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.0\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R

But I can't run the same command successfully in task scheduler.
I get the following error messages:
*** Failed to execute folder pair upload_photos. Could not locate folder \photos\d$\Projects\warner\wwwroot\

What's the problem?
The permission issue? But I can run it manually.
Someone says that it's the user account issue with UNC path. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance it appears you have one of the following errors:

1. `\photos\d$\Projects\warner\wwwroot\`
   isn't a valid path. Either `photos` is
   a machine, so there should be a
   double back slash at the start, or it's a folder
   and should be after the drive
   letter.
2. The permissions are incorrect for the user account under which the task is running.

Answer (score 1):

```
* Failed to execute folder pair upload_photos. Could not locate folder \photos\d$\Projects\warner\wwwroot\
```

is a strange behaviour,  it has to be "\photos\d$"  or "\\photos\d$"? (note the double backslash)

Anyway, if you are sure that the scheduled job is running with the proper user rights you can paste the command in a batch file and call that batch via task scheduler.

Comment: @John Gardeniers...I agree with you (+1), I was writing my answer when you have posted your one :-)

Comment: that happens a lot, you'll get used to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I changed the settings to only run when user is logged in the task ran successfully.